How to convert video to video note telegram bot (Aiogram 3.11)?
How to make a telegram circle from a user-sent video and send it back to the chat?
@router.message(Command("Get_circle"))
async def cmd_circle(message: Message):
     await message.answer_video_note(video_note="videoid")

The bot sends the video that the user sent

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should process video to circle by yourself.  You need to download user's video, and then send it to user. not just resending video-id
